# How to start activity as its first created

Tags: android, sms, onstart

How to start same activity again as its created first time. I used INTET to start activity again . but If user press home button at mobile this intent not works . is there anyother way to startactivity as its first created  when its in background. Pls help this I shall be very thankful to  you for this.

```
private void sendNextMessage(){
    Log.i("Is there are sms sendNextMessage", thereAreSmsToSend()+"");
    if(thereAreSmsToSend()){
        Log.i("sendNextMessage mMessageSentParts", mMessageSentParts+"");
        Log.i("sendNextMessage mMessageSentTotalParts", mMessageSentTotalParts+"");
        Log.i("sendNextMessage mMessageSentCount", mMessageSentCount+"");
        Log.i("sendNextMessage Phone list", list_phone.get(mMessageSentCount)+"");
        sendSMS(list_phone.get(mMessageSentCount),list_MESSAGE_BODY.get(mMessageSentCount));
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "All SMS have been sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new AddNewCategory().execute();
        h.removeCallbacks(r);
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // I used this code to start activity again but if user press home button this intent not works .
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(i);
                Log.e("Time", "60000 intent");
                h.removeCallbacks(r);
            }
        }, 30000);
        h.removeCallbacks(r);
        h.removeCallbacks(r);          
    }
}
```

Comment: how u create activity can u post code?

Comment: Of course , I had posted it

Comment: you want to start same activity again when created?

Comment: Yes I want to start same activity again

Comment: so in above code it doesnt start? ur intent code???

Comment: its working fine , but when user is interacting with another application this is stop working.

Comment: with other application means?example?

Comment: you can use service for the same

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply..! Like if user press home button at mobile this intent code not start activty. To start activity this must be in front of user.

Comment: I never used services before . Can u tell me about services

Answer (score 0):

How about using the SharedPreferences with a boolean value;

Make a class for this:

```
private Context context;

public boolean saveFirsTime(boolean firstime) 
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();         
        editor.putBoolean("FirstTime", firstime);                                       
        return editor.commit();
    }   

public boolean loadFirsTime() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences();       
    boolean firstimeMap = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("FirstTime", true);      
    return firstimeMap;
}
public boolean clearFirsTime() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.remove("FirstTime");

    return editor.commit();
}

private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences() {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("SharedPrefereneces",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
```

And then implement `saveFirstTime(false)` in your Activity onCreate();

Comment: Does its works as background . when its not in the front of user.

Comment: If you are using AsyncTask you can getSharedPreferences too. That's  your question? I don't quite understand what do you mean

Comment: Mean when user is interacting with another application this application works or not?

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply ...! My question is that to startactivity again its must be in front of user, But how can I startactivity again when user is interacting with other application?

Comment: So your question is not to initialize an activity as its first created, you should look forward to send messages while the application is on background.

Comment: Edit your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Write a service and broadcast receiver something like below :

This Activity start activity on reboot similarly u can write ur event on which activity is called :

```
public class BootStartUpReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving

              // Start Service On Boot Start Up
              Intent service = new Intent(context, TestService.class);
              context.startService(service);

              //Start App On Boot Start Up
              Intent App = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
              App.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              context.startActivity(App);


       }
}
```

Comment: Still same issue . when I press home button at my mobile its not working context.startactivity(app); if I agin take this screen in front of me its works fine

Comment: no no this was just an example ..u need to write the event also this above will start activity on reboot similarly u need to write custom broadcast..